# D class invariant calling const functions

Tags: d, invariants

Why does the following throw a compiler error:

```
class A
{
public:
    int f() const
    {
        return 5;
    }

protected:
    invariant()
    {
        assert (f() == 5);
    }
}
```

`main.d(14): Error: cannot call public/export function f from invariant`.

I understand the concept of invariant; you want to check the state of the class between every public call to a method.

However, immutable or const member functions cannot alter the state of the class (unless `this` was passed?), so invariant checks surrounding those functions are redundant. The invariant call could be left aside and no infinite loop would appear, casting the compiler error wrong.

---

I came to this since I create hierarchies with objects, which define:

```
bool hasParent() const
{
    return (parent !is null);
}
```

using this little function is easier within the class, but possibly outside too. But defining it public defies invariant().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's most likely an omission. Feel free to file an enhancement request on [Bugzilla](http://d.puremagic.com/issues/).